# 1.54 e-ink without driver

Tags: spi, display, wires

i wan’t to know if is possible to use  [this raw e-ink display](https://www.robotics.org.za/image/cache/catalog/waveshare/W12561/W12561-000-500x500.jpg)  with arduino. if it’s possible to directly connect cables from this ribbon cable to arduino without any driver pcb and control it with 3 or 4 wire SPI. 
[the pinout of the display is on the 6th page](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/7/77/1.54inch_e-Paper_Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: Please add more info, not just a  link to a picture!

Comment: i’ve just posted the datasheet

Comment: DONT CROSS POST!

Comment: See figure 7-5 in the datasheet you linked. There it shows you how to connect the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of yes and kind of no.

It requires external circuitry, but that circuitry isn't a "driver board" in the traditional sense.

An e-Ink display requires high voltages to charge the electrostatic cells. Traditionally that would be provided using an external "driver" circuit - a *boost* voltage converter.

However this display has that boost converter built in - though it doesn't have *all* the components, because they just won't fit.

You need to provide the diodes, switching MOSFET, and inductor, etc as shown on page 18 of the datasheet.  Nothing less will do.

Comment: thanks. i was thinking that i just solder few wires to a ribbon cable but i understood that there must be a lot of other components